# Android Intents: Sending message through email or sms, using the built-in app picker

Tags: android, android-intent

GOAL: When user taps the `Send to...` button, I want android to open a list of apps that can send messages (email, sms, etc.). The user picks one. That apps opens with text message already fed in.

Here is the code I use to try to achieve that:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.setType("text/plain");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, outputTextView.getText());
 if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
     startActivity(intent);
```

PROBLEM: When running it, a list of available apps is correctly displayed (Gmail, Hangouts, Messenger, Keep, Translate, etc.). If I pick GMail, it works fine. **BUT:**  If I pick Hangout, Keep, Translate or any of the other suggested apps, my text is not displayed in those.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Try this code for Sharing!");
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm trying to share data....");

        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with");
        chooserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Comment: Your code works better than mine in creating a more functional list of avalaible apps. In your version, I need to replace the string "I'm trying to share data...." with `outputTextView.getText()` to which I must append `.toString()`. My original code was missing the `toString` call. Both your fix and mine make this achieve my stated goal. So I am marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: yeah you can easily do that by replacing that line. Happy that it helps you.. Thanks..